# How many degrees of freedom do orthogonal skew-symmetric matrices have?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

$n$ by $n$ real orthogonal matrices [have $n (n-1)/2$ degrees of freedom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375344/parameters-to-represent-degrees-of-freedom-in-n-times-n-orthogonal-real-matric). So do the skew-symmetric matrices.

But what about matrices that are both skew-symmetric and orthogonal?

Is the number of such matrices finite for any given $n$? If not, how many degrees of freedom do they have?

---

We [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408502/54642) that such matrices exist only if $n$ is even, in which case they are equal to

$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n/2}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\
-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

*up to an orthogonal change of basis*. However, the number of their degrees of freedom is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space of all such is $G/G_x$ where $G$ is the whole orthogonal group and $G_x$ is the stabilizer in $G$ of your particular example under the action $g\times x=gxg^{-1}$. The dimension of the latter is $>0$, since at the very least orthogonal matrices with $2\times 2$ blocks *scalar* are in that centralizer. More generally, upon writing out the centralizer condition, it is a copy of $U(n)$ inside $O(2n,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: There is an analysis here http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/webpage/antiortho.ps.  Didn't have time to read it.  It's the same approach, though.

Comment: I didn't really understand this answer, I guess because I'm not that familiar with group theory. Does this mean that we have a formula for the degrees of freedom as a function of $n$, and in that case, what is that formula?

Comment: @fredgoodman How do I open the file?

Comment: @HelloGoodby, download the linked file and open it with something that recognizes postscript files, e.g. a ps to pdf converter, or your tex/latex system, or Preview on Apple machines.